# How to JOIN a 2nd table with condition based on 3rd JOIN table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, group-by

I need to join 2 tables with the 2nd table with JOIN condition that is based on the 3rd JOIN table.

The problem is, I couldn't get the value from 3rd JOIN table while still joining the 2nd table.

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wZ8JUFhKmN1E8hSM6NSJt5/2)

```
Table A: users
-------
user_id INT PRIMARY
```

```
Table B: orders
-------
order_id INT PRIMARY
user_id INT
invoice_id INT
```

```
Table C: invoices
-------
invoice_id INT PRIMARY
invoice_status VARCHAR [voided, paid]
```

This is what I wish to do:

```sql
SELECT 
    A.user_id,
    B.order_id,
    C.invoice_id,
    C.invoice_status
FROM users A
LEFT JOIN orders B 
    ON (B.user_id = A.user_id
        AND C.invoice_status = 'paid')
LEFT JOIN invoices C
    ON (C.invoice_id = B.invoice_id)
```

The 9th line `AND C.invoice_status = 'paid')` is referring to table C which has not been joined yet, so this query will cause `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'C.invoice_status' in 'on clause'`

The reason I cannot have this condition in `WHERE` clause is because I still want to return all users records regardless of whether they have any order or 'paid' invoice or not. So adding `WHERE invoice_status = 'paid'` will NOT return users without any order and users with `invoice_status` = 'voided'.

Also, when a user has two orders linked to two different invoice records, but 1 invoice's `invoice_status` is 'paid', while the other is 'voided', I only want to return the 'paid' record. There can be many `voided` invoices, but only 1 'paid' invoice record.

By the way, this is enforced: `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`, so I can't do `GROUP BY user_id` without having some kind of aggregated or condition on `order_id` & `invoice_id` fields.

---

```
SELECT 
    A.user_id,
    B.order_id,
    C.invoice_id,
    C.invoice_status
FROM users A
LEFT JOIN orders B 
    ON (B.user_id = A.user_id)
LEFT JOIN invoices C
    ON (C.invoice_id = B.invoice_id);
```

| user_id | order_id | invoice_id | invoice_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | voided |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | paid |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | voided |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

My desired result:

| user_id | order_id | invoice_id | invoice_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | paid |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | voided |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Each `user_id` must only return once, with `invoice_status` = 'paid' being the preferred row when there are multiple related orders.

---

Appreciate it if anyone has any idea how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: In your case you need to go with stored procedure.

Comment: instead of `C.invoice_status = 'paid'`, you can add `NOT EXISTS (...)` to the `ON` clause for `B` to exclude unwanted rows

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` function And number the rows according to `user_id` and sort according to `invoice_status` then fetch the first row

```
SELECT user_id,
       order_id,
       invoice_id,
       invoice_status
FROM
  (SELECT 
    A.user_id,
    B.order_id,
    C.invoice_id,
    C.invoice_status,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.user_id ORDER BY C.invoice_status) AS num
  FROM users A
  LEFT JOIN orders B 
    ON (B.user_id = A.user_id)
  LEFT JOIN invoices C
    ON (C.invoice_id = B.invoice_id)) t
WHERE num = 1
```

*[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da175bd78aa59f4f1403d3dd1f0e8e9b)*

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it by using `EXISTS` thanks to [ProGu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17016144/progu)'s comment.

```sql
SELECT 
    A.user_id,
    B.order_id,
    C.invoice_id,
    C.invoice_status
FROM users A
LEFT JOIN orders B 
    ON B.user_id = A.user_id
    AND EXISTS( SELECT 
            1
        FROM
            invoices
        WHERE
            invoices.invoice_id = B.invoice_id
                AND invoices.invoice_status = 'paid')
LEFT JOIN invoices C
    ON C.invoice_id = B.invoice_id
```

| user_id | order_id | invoice_id | invoice_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | paid |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Thanks!